# Can I assume that the unix timestamp is going to be incremented with go?

Tags: go, timestamp

example...

```
func MakeTimestamp() int64 {
    return time.Now().UTC().UnixNano() / int64(time.Nanosecond)
}
```

This will create something like `1539222678608597000`

I'm storing this data on mongodb and I will eventually use something like:

```
db.getCollection('xxxxx').find({ "timestamp":{$lte: 1539194688262205259, $gte: 1539176688262205057} },{"venue": 1},{"product":0})
```

https://play.golang.org/p/--rHy3ms1c5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, timestamps are not monotonic. They are subject to clock synchronization by the OS and [can skip forward and backward](https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-and-why-the-leap-second-affected-cloudflare-dns/).

That's why Go 1.9 added the [monotonic part to time.Time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#hdr-Monotonic_Clocks). You can now always reliably subtract two time.Time values that have been obtained with time.Now(), but any formatting will discard the monotonic part.

Timestamps are therefore not suitable for robust chronological ordering, but in many practical cases they are "good enough". You have to decide for yourself if it works for you, given the occasional inaccuracies. (Never use them in software that runs on laptops and other mobile devices. Standby modes can cause all kinds of weird clock issues, like time jumping several *hours* into the future.)